# Getting Error when Moving Laravel site to Localhost

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I am new in laravel i have a laravel site in my test server.now i want to transfer that site into localhost.
i have changed database connection into app/config/database.php

but when i run the site it gives me an error

[image]

my composer.json code looks like this

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "laravel/framework": "4.2.*",
        "cartalyst/sentry": "2.1.*",
        "thujohn/pdf": "dev-master"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "app/commands",
            "app/controllers",
            "app/models",
            "app/database/migrations",
            "app/database/seeds",
            "app/tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable"
}
```

Please help me to run the site in my local system

Comment: You have to add service provider of what you had installed package.

Comment: how can i do so? @SetKyarWaLar

Comment: Check with your `local/app.php` service provider array and `app.php` service provider array.

Comment: 'Dinesh\Barcode\BarcodeServiceProvider', already in service provider array but file location is different app/config/app.php @SetKyarWaLar. my laravel version is 4.2

Answer (score -1):

Begin by installing this package through Composer. Edit your project's composer.json file to require dinesh/barcode.

```
"require": {
    "laravel/framework": "5.0.x",
    "dinesh/barcode": "5.0.*@dev"
}
```

Next, update Composer from the Terminal:

```
composer update
```

Comment: @KaranAdhikari that's impossible, it had nothing to do with entire site but just that class, you must have done wrong somewhere else.

Comment: did you add this line  `"laravel/framework": "5.0.x",` too? if you did, you were not supposed to do this.